# Combining multiple shell script, sed and user input in a single script

Tags: python, bash, shell, sed

At the moment I am using two separate shell script to get the job done.

1) Listing the current directory and saving it as a .html file (first listing only the root directory followed by complete listing)

```
tree -L 1 -dH ./ >> /Volumes/BD/BD-V1.html && tree -H ./ >> /Volumes/BD/BD-V1.html
```

2) Using sed to remove unwanted lines (I'm on mac)

```
sed -i '' '/by Francesc Rocher/d' /Volumes/BD/BD-V1.html && sed -i '' '/by Steve Baker/d' /Volumes/BD/BD-V1.html  && sed -i '' '/by Florian Sesser/d' /Volumes/BD/BD-V1.html
```

Now I want to combine them as a single script with user input for the file path. I was trying to do with python but no success

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["tree", "-d", "-L", "1"])
```

The above one can list the directory but I couldn't save the output (I have to do this inside of python), I tried something like this but didn't get work.

```
 file = open('out.txt', 'w')
 import subprocess
 variation_string = subprocess.call(["tree", "-d", "-L", "1"])  
 file.write(variation_string)
 file.close()
```

Also I'm not sure how to implement sed :(

edit: I'm a beginner

Comment: Since you obviously are a beginner with both, shell commands and Python, I would recommend not using both right now. Stay with the shell, and take your time to write a shell script which does what you want. Shell scripts can take user input just fine, via command like arguments, for instance.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke thanks, now I did them all in a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redirect the stdout to a file object:

```
from subprocess import check_call

with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    check_call(["tree", "-d", "-L", "1"],stdout=f)
```

In your code you are basically trying to write the `return code` as that is what call returns to the file which would raise an error as `write` expects a string. If you wanted to store the output of running a command you would use `check_output`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the subprocess module. You can create another process that runs your command, and then communicate with it. This will give you the output.

```
import subprocess
file = open('out.txt', 'w')
...
command = "tree -d -L 1"
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
...
file.write(output)
file.close()
```